# AZERTY keycode with GLFW3

Tags: c++, c, keyboard, glfw, azerty-keyboard

I am using GLFW3 and I want to get keyboard events with an AZERTY configuration.

I used glfwGetKey to get the state of the keys but that function looks to send me keys with a QWERTY configuration and when I use QWERTY, that the same problem, keys looks to be in an AZERTY there.

So I reuse the callback but there are 2 problems. The keycode is the same that with glfwGetKey (AZERTY / QWERTY problem) and the callback isn't called immediately when I hold a key, but after a little time.

Comment: GLFW doesn't care what layout you are using, if you look at [the documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__keys.html), the physical keys are named after what they would be with a US layout. So that is the intended behavior. And for the repeat key : are you sure the callback isn't called, or are you just not checking for the [`GLFW_REPEAT`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/input.html#input_keyboard) action ?

Comment: Yep, I know, when I change the layout keys change too but when I'm in AZERTY, keys looks like in QWERTY ( example : Z => W ).
I don't talk about GLFW_REPEAT but about the frequency of call of the key callback.